# What is the difference between apt and apt-get

Tags: raspbian, apt

What is the difference between 'apt' and 'apt-get'?

I have seen both used in various places and they appear to do the same thing, is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

Try reading the `man` which will explain all!

Basically `apt` is the user interface, `apt-get` is the backend command line.